# Long Running Processes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want kick off a long running process from a web Page (MVC5), and send the request to a windows service (unless there is a better way?). The catch is, I don't want the process to be started twice.

The process will broadcast progress using SignalR (I have that part sorted), but using .Net 4.5 - how can I make sure the first request starts, and the second request gets rejected (even if they are milliseconds apart).

I know we could use Windows Service, database. Ideas around best practice for this?

Comment: I have removed tag(s) from your question's title based on  _[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles)_ where the consensus is **no** _they should not_.

Answer (score 0):

You can put it in a key / value pair like a cache that will map the request to the process. There is a `Cache` object you use in ASP.NET. One caveat would be to check the Windows Service if the key is not in the cache. The database approach is safer in terms of persistence. So you don't have to poll the Windows Service. Either way, you will need to toggle the key / value pair when the process is done.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [hangfire](http://hangfire.io/).

With hangfire you can run some long running background tasks and have an overview of all current tasks on the dashboard. Try it out, i think it is pretty cool.